# SwiftUI RoundedRectangle cutting off on the bottom

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a swift `RoundedRectangle`:

```
ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
            Group {
                HStack {
                    if let height = height {
                        if height != "" {
                            aboutMeItem(info: height, image: "ruler").frame(minWidth: 20)
                        }
                    }
                }
                .frame(minHeight: 70, maxHeight: 70)
                .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15).stroke(Color("darkGrey"), lineWidth: 3))
                .padding([.leading,.top,.trailing])
            }
        }
```

My output is:

[image]

For some reason the bottom line is being slightly cut out and you cant see the full line width.

Iv tried removing the view below it incase something was covering it but that wasn't it. I've tried messing with the `frame` `min` and `maxHeight`, but thats still the same regardless of the same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use `strokeBorder` instead of `stroke`.

another thing that you done was `.padding([.leading,.top,.trailing])` so you did not include bottom! but I think `strokeBorder` would cover that as well.

---

```
ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
        Group {
            HStack {
                if let height = height {
                    if height != "" {
                        aboutMeItem(info: height, image: "ruler").frame(minWidth: 20)
                    }
                }
            }
            .frame(minHeight: 70, maxHeight: 70)
            .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15).strokeBorder(Color("darkGrey"), lineWidth: 3)) // <<: Here
            .padding([.leading,.top,.trailing]) // <<: Here!!! you did not used .bottom
        }
    }
```

Comment: strokeBorder worked, without needing to apply any .trailing padding